# How to introduce new line characters with iTextSharp

Tags: vb.net, pdf, itext

I have written following code to write text in PDF and i want to break the line after some text .

```
 Dim document As Document

    document = New Document(PageSize.A4, 5.0F, 20.0F, 20.0F, 20.0F)

    Try

        Dim writer As PdfWriter
        writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))

        document.Open()

        Dim spacing As Integer

        spacing = 0

        Dim curY, lineHeight As Double

        curY = document.Top
        lineHeight = 0

        Const maxPerLine As Integer = 3


        For i As Integer = 0 To 5

            Dim table As PdfPTable
            table = New PdfPTable(4)

            table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER
            table.TotalWidth = 200.0F
            table.LockedWidth = True

            Dim cell As PdfPCell
            cell = New PdfPCell(New Phrase("hello \n" + i + "\n" + "wass up ?" ))
            cell.Colspan = 4
            cell.HorizontalAlignment = 0
            cell.Border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER
            cell.Padding = 30.0F
            table.AddCell(cell)

            table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left + spacing, curY, writer.DirectContent)

            spacing = spacing + 200

            lineHeight = Math.Max(lineHeight, table.TotalHeight)

            If 0 = (i + 1) Mod maxPerLine Then

                curY = curY - lineHeight
                spacing = 0
                lineHeight = 0

            End If

        Next

    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally

        document.Close()


    End Try
```

i have tried with Paragraph but still i am not able to enter texts into new line.

I have read the doc of iTextSharp they have written if you want to break line then use "\n" but it is not working.

How can i break line after some text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, is to use `PdfPCell` in *composite mode* (you're using *text mode*). Composite mode gets into play when you use `AddElement`:

```
Dim cell As PdfPCell
cell = New PdfPCell()
cell.AddElement(New Paragraph("line 1"))
cell.AddElement(New Paragraph("line 2"))
```

Note that you can't set the alignment at the level of the `PdfPCell` in this case. When using *composite mode*, you have to set the alignment at the level of the elements (in this case at the level of the `Paragraph`).

Comment: using Environment.NewLine i dont have to add seperate paragraphs